# Яблоки, но инжир

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Понимаю, что тут не очень любят вопросы "почему", поэтому просто поделюсь наблюдением.
Почему-то, скажем, яблоки, персики или абрикосы бывают и в единственном, и во множественном числе, а вот инжир — одинаково в обоих числах. Можно провести аналогию с мелкими ягодами (малина, кизил), но инжир отнюдь не мелкий и по размерам сопоставим с абрикосами и даже персиками.

Comment: >Понимаю, что тут не очень любят вопросы "почему"  
  
Только некорректные. Когда ответ заведомо не предполагает ответа "Потому что...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ясно, что причина не в самом фрукте. Мы же можем сказать "фиги" или "смоквы", а ведь это тот же самый инжир.

Кстати, идея на уровне бреда: может эти слова изначально использовались по-разному?  Может, инжиром называлось дерево, как груша и т.п.

Answer (score 3):

Отчего-то так устоялось. Может, потому, что его не штуками измеряли, а сразу какой-то мерой. А у хурмы, например, нет множественного числа. В Крыму есть такой фрукт - "зизифус", он всегда в единственном числе. "Одна зизифусина" вроде не скажешь.

Comment: Ага, есть у нас такой - очень хорош от давления. Но ведь можно сказать "зизифусы"? Или нет?

Answer (score 2):

Инжир - не плод, а кушанье. 
Несчетное понятие, нельзя сказать "два инжира",только "два плода инжира". Или две фиги.

Вот вопрос "Почему нельзя сказать два инжира?" был бы действительно некорректным, ибо это данность

> Кстати, идея на уровне бреда: может эти слова изначально использовались по-разному? Может, инжиром называлось дерево, как груша и т.п.

Это не совсем бред. Слова действительно использовались по-разному, только дело не в дереве.
"Инжир" используется примерно как "изюм". 
А вот дерево исторически как раз было фиговым, не инжирным.

Comment: Вот спасибо! Я чувствовала, что в этом что-то есть!

Comment: Почему не плод, а кушанье? Инжир — это вполне себе плод.

Comment: Нет. Не плод, а ***плоды***

Иначе получится, что изюм и курага - тоже плод. Или кулубника с вишней.
Но они-то никак не *единичный* плод, как яблоко или скажем, груша.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, здесь какое-то недоразумение)

Можно свободно сказать : два, три, четыре инжира! И писатель Фазиль Искандер **как бы тоже** не подозревает о "запрете" на множественное число :

> Чунка снова высунулся из листвы, **дотянулся до хорошего инжира,** сорвал его и с улыбкой, отводя руку, показал, что собирается его кинуть тетушке Хрисуле. ...
> Тетушка Хрисула замотала головой, задвигала руками, как бы заново залопотала, хотя и до этого не переставала лопотать, всем своим видом показывая, что вот уж от кого она теперь никогда **не примет ни одного инжира**. ...
> После этого она протянула руку в корзину и, давая знать, что не слишком долго выбирает, **вытащила оттуда три инжира** и, показав смеющемуся Чунке, что она вытащила **только три инжира**, и, как бы дав ему осознать проявленную скромность, она в виде маленькой награды за эту скромность **вытащила еще один инжир.**
> (Ф.Искандер, "Сандро из Чегема",  Нацкорпус)

Две хурмы и три инжира, что здесь необычного?

Answer (score 0):

Да, хороший фрукт. Если регулярно есть зизифус, давление будет, как у космонавта. Но "зизифусы", мне кажется, сказать нельзя. Купить немного зизифуса. Как инжира.